# Update a large number of records in SQL Server - poor performance

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a simple query to update a very large number of records ~20 million. The update is done on a remote server from where the original update statement runs and there are several joins in the query.

Wanted to see if anybody has any tips on making this query run a bit faster. it's currently running for hours.

I thought about getting a list of unique id's from a select statement and then run the update on the remote server but I'm sure there are better ways to get this done.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some actual details? Currently your post is like "I have a racecar that I want to go faster, how do I make it faster?". We need details like the table structure, the update statement, indexes etc...but 20 million rows in a single update is likely to horribly slow. It is generally best to break into smaller sets of around 10-100 thousand at a time.

Comment: examine the query execution plan - does it suggest any indexes need to be created?

Comment: Index exists. I'm looking for a very general idea and strategies on updating a large number of rows. What's are some things to avoid/do. This is a simple update statement to update a single value to zero, indexes exist but since it's a very large number of rows. Some strategies would help.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by batches or use bulkcopy.

Here is an example on bulkcopy and update

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy--Bulk-Insert-records-and-Update-existing-rows-if-record-exists-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

A proper index cannot hurt.